# Query for certificate of other members

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

Is possible to ask the Membership Service Provider a certificate of other members which join the network?
I've looked at the MSP interface but I didn't find an answer to this doubt.
I mean if it is possible to do this from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from fabric v1.2 you can use the [discovery CLI](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discovery-cli.html) to query a peer of the peers in the network.

You can also use any SDK API to query the list of peers.